# WPF bound object update notification

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a TreeView with a few objects bound to it, let's say something like this:

```
public class House
    {
        public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
        public List<Person> People { get; set; }

        public House()
        {
            this.Rooms = new List<Room>();
            this.People = new List<Person>();
        }

        public void BuildRoom(string name)
        {
            this.Rooms.Add(new Room() { Name = name });
        }

        public void DestroyRoom(string name)
        {
            this.Rooms.Remove(new Room() { Name = name });
        }

        public void PersonEnter(string name)
        {
            this.People.Add(new Person() { Name = name });
        }

        public void PersonLeave(string name)
        {
            this.People.Remove(new Person() { Name = name });
        }
    }

    public class Room
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The TreeView is watching over the House object, whenever a room is built / destroyed or a person enters / leaves, my tree view updates itself to show the new state of the house (I omitted some implementation details for simplicity).

What I want is to know the exact moment when this update finishes, so I can do something right there, the thing is that I created an indicator of the selected item, and when something moves, I need to update said indicator's position, that's the reason I need it exactly when the tree view updates.

Let me know if you know a solution to this.

Also, the code is not perfect (DestroyRoom and PersonLeave), but you get the idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have the indicator as part of the item template and bind its visibility to IsSelected?  That seems a more natural approach than trying to hook into the drawing cycle, but I'm not sure what your constraints are.

Comment: @itwolson: We could, but that bring up some more problems that we already fixed in this one. We already spent a couple of hours here, and this is the only problem left. Of course if we can't solve it soon, we will have to take a different approach, which will probably be what you suggested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an ObservableCollection<T> and wrap it in a CollectionView to get a bindable CurrentItem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview_members.aspx

Comment: Actually this is what I have an ObservableCollection instead of lists, I shouldn't have avoided that detail. Anyway, when the CollectionChanged event happens, the treeview has still not updated its items, so that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using a hierarchical data template? - If not you will not get sub items. Is the tree view's itemsSource property binded correctly to the observable collection? (Try binding a label's content to the collection's count and another to the collection to test this - should get a number in one and the class name in the other).